# How to stop Django from serving files locally?

Tags: python, django, browser, browser-cache, django-staticfiles

I need to prevent local Django/runserver from serving my static files (I want to test whitenoise locally). The `--nostatic` flag is supposed to do just that.

```
python manage.py runserver --nostatic
```

But I still get 200s (successful) for my static files. So then I set `debug = False` but still get 200s! I even commented out `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` from `INSTALLED_APPS`. But this did not work either. How could my static files still be served successfully - it's usually not this hard to break things. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what nostatic actually does; I was expecting to get 404s.

Comment: Aren't the files serving from your static files directory? Did you ran `collectstatics`?

Comment: Are you sure you've removed WhiteNoise?

Comment: I actually didn't comment-out the middleware 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware'. Once I did that I got 404s for the static files. Thanks. Feel free to make that into an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in the comments, but for future reference the answer was to make sure that `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` was removed from the `MIDDLEWARE` list.

Answer (score 0):

First, clear browser's cache because your browser will still keep the cache of the static files of Django . *On Google Chrome, you can open the page to clear cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which also works on Firefox. Or you can empty cache and reload the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox). Or you can use the Google Chrome extension [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) to clear cache.

And according to my experiments, if I set `WhiteNoiseMiddleware` of [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) to [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#middleware) in `settings.py` and run the Django server with `--nostatic` as shown below, the static files are still served:

```py
# "settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Here
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

```
python manage.py runserver --nostatic
```

And according to my experiments, if I don't set `WhiteNoiseMiddleware` of [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) to [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#middleware) in `settings.py` and run the Django server with `--nostatic` as shown below, the static files are not served:

```py
# "settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

```
python manage.py runserver --nostatic
```